# Is it possible to get back from VELTINS-Arena to Duisburg by public transportation on a weekday night?

Tags: public-transport, germany, football

So I am spending a couple of nights in Duisburg in beginning of February and are now considering my options. There is a football game between Schalke 04 and Hertha Berlin that interests me on the 4th of February at 20:45. It is a cup game so I guess it will be finished somewhere between 22:30 and 23:25. Is it possible to use public transportation to get back to Duisburg after the game. I have searched and there are connections but when football fans are involved it may not be the case and hence this question.

Comment: What makes you think they reduce service due to a football game? In general, football games would rather lead to additional services, if anything.

Comment: You can use any of the official on line public transit planners in Germany to find out schedules, and you can assume those to be correct. 
The Germans really want you to take public transport to that game. So much that free travel in the entire VRR area is even included in the ticket price. So you not only can count on being able to get to/from the game using public transit, you do not even need to buy a separate ticket, as Duisburg is within the VRR area.

Comment: @FDMS sometimes this happens due to the rivalry between fans. Even in small Stockholm a commuter train station was shut down after a derby causing me to have a long walk to other means of communication.

Comment: @KristvanBesien - would accept this as an answer if you morph it into one! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any of the official on line public transit planners in Germany to find out schedules, and you can assume those to be correct.

The Germans really want you to take public transport to that game. So much that free travel in the entire VRR area is even included in the ticket price.

So you not only can count on being able to get to/from the game using public transit, you do not even need to buy a separate ticket, as Duisburg is within the VRR area